# vue2-editor How to use vee-validate

Tags: vuejs2, vee-validate

```
<b-col><vue-editor name="content" v-model="formData.content" v-validate="required" :class="{'vue-editor': false, error:errors.has('content')}"/></b-col>
```

If you try to use it as above, it will not be used

Can I use vee-validate with vue2-editor ??

Comment: could you provide the link of the used package and your data object

Comment: main.js import VeeValidate from 'vee-validate',import VueEditor from 'vue2-editor' (Vue.use(VueEditor),Vue.use(VeeValidate) 
I would like to give you a link ...

Comment: Here's an example of [validating custom components](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/forms#example-vee-validate).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use vee-validate with vue2-editor

but name="content" should be  `data-vv-name="content"`